# Are these two ways of looking at conditional linear regression the same?

Tags: regression, mathematical-statistics, linear, conditional-expectation

Let $X$, $\hat{S}$, $\hat{V}$ be random variables, with means (and conditional means, if necessary) $=0$.

Is $\beta^*(X) = \frac{\mathrm{Cov}(\hat{S}, \hat{V}|X)}{\mathrm{Var}(\hat{S}|X)}$ the solution to the (variational) problem:

$$ \min_{\beta(x) : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}} \mathrm{Var}(\hat{V} - \beta(X)\hat{S}) $$ ?

The only thing I was able to come up with, is that $\beta^*(x)$ solves the following problem:
$$ \min_{\beta \in \mathbb{R}} \mathrm{Var} [ \hat{V} - \beta \hat{S}| X]$$
Maybe the two are related?

**Context**

I was taking a look at Andreas Grau's PhD thesis [[download](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Andreas_Grau3/publication/36419705_Applications_of_Least-Squares_Regressions_to_Pricing_and_Hedging_of_Financial_Derivatives/links/54b8e8320cf2c27adc4902cf/Applications-of-Least-Squares-Regressions-to-Pricing-and-Hedging-of-Financial-Derivatives.pdf?origin=publication_detail)] where on page 9, he implicitly uses this fact.

He provides a German reference, which I'm not able to read:
H. Scheid, editor. Sch¨uler Duden: Die Mathematik, chapter Regression, page 340ff. Dudenverlag,
3rd. edition, 1991.